# python strip() in reading lines from a file

Tags: python

when i try to use strip() in the following condition, the output is a little different.

```
for line in tagfile:
    tag_name = line.strip("<>")
    print tag_name
```

the output is 
    `strike>`

but if I use the following method

```
 tag_name = "<strike>"
 print tag_name.strip("<>")
```

the output is
    `strike`

Anybody who can help this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the newline at the end of the line, strip does not go beyond it since you are not specifying newline as a token. Try this:

```
for line in tagfile:
    tag_name = line.strip("<>\n")
    print tag_name
```

or use this:

```
for line in tagfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    tag_name = line.strip("<>")
    print tag_name
```

Comment: It works but only if the '\n' is next to '>', when there is space between them, it fails.